# Using IIF and AND in SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have a table like below

[image]

I want to hide the rows where ALL 3 columns are 0. All the columns are of INT data type

My expression is like so:

```
    =IIF((Fields!PastVal.Value=0) AND (Fields!DatePay=0) AND (Fields!Line.Value=0),False,True)
```

But no data is returned except the column label(heading). What could be wrong with my express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Row Visibility? The **True** or **False** is for **Hiding** the Row yet you set it to false if they equal 0.

```
=IIF((Fields!PastVal.Value=0) AND (Fields!DatePay=0) AND (Fields!Line.Value=0), True, False)
```

That still doesn't fix the issue though - some columns should have been displayed since you have data in your example.

Are your data rows using SUM? If so, your expression would need to SUM also.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!PastVal.Value) = 0 AND SUM(Fields!DatePay.Value) = 0 AND SUM(Fields!Line.Value) = 0, True, False)
```

Comment: Thanks Hannover. My expression from Sql is like this: ISNULL(DatePay,0) AS DatePay. No SUM is applied to the columns in SSRS. Any difference with that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter on the tablix, where you simply add 3 conditions, one for each of the 3 fields:

[image]

Use the `<>` as operator on each condition, and simply specify `0` as the Value rather than using an expression.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the reply. That was a typing error. 
I still cannot get it to work. Now I get the error:

 "Cannot compare data types of System.Int32 and System.String.     Please check the data type returned by the filter expression"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your kind suggestion. My expression was right all the while, but because I had a grouping on my report, I had to to set the Visibility through the Group Properties by clicking on Details. Prior to that, I was applying the filter by right clicking the detail row in the report body but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your contribution. My fault. My report had a group level and because I was applying the filter by right clicking on my tablix, that did not work. I had to do it by right clicking on Detail in the Row Group.